# How to sum all count(case) subcolumns?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm creating a table that can count all 'abnormal' data from three columns and sum those columns as the total.

```
SELECT

  COUNT(CASE WHEN p_eyes <> 'Normal' THEN 1 END) AS 'abnormalEyes',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN p_ears <> 'Normal' THEN 1 END) AS 'abnormalEars',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN p_nose <> 'Normal' THEN 1 END) AS 'abnormalNose'

FROM student_physical_record_exam_grade_eleven;
```

This will count all the not 'Normal' from those three columns.

Is there any way I can total those three columns as 'Eyes/Ears/Nose'?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code - although, at its heart, I suspect that this problem stems from a poorly designed table

Comment: You can use a subquery. SELECT abnormalEyes + abnormalEars + abnormalNose as 'Eyes/Ears/Nose' FROM ( your query );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just sum these results, you could add them. The easiest way of doing this is with a subquery:

```
SELECT *, abnormalEyes + abnormalEars + abnormalNose AS totalAbnormal
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN p_eyes <> 'Normal' THEN 1 END) AS abnormalEyes,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN p_ears <> 'Normal' THEN 1 END) AS abnormalEars,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN p_nose <> 'Normal' THEN 1 END) AS abnormalNose
FROM   student_physical_record_exam_grade_eleven) t
```

Comment: Can I ask what that 't' means?

Comment: @JinAnonuevo in MySQL every table expression (in this case, a subquery) must have a name. Since in this case we don't really care about the subquery's name (i.e., we aren't going to use it anywhere), I just used `t` (short for "table"). But you could use any descriptive name you like.